# Recuperar archivos directorio local

Tags: git, vscode, terminal

Necesito vuestra ayuda! He leído otras respuestas a problemas similares y antes de hacer nada y perder toda la información del ordenador.

Estando trabajando con la terminal y git en una carpeta ubicada en el escritorio (en este proyecto tengo commits guardados), cambié la ruta de trabajo para otro proyecto y poco después observé que Visual Code Studio tenia todos los archivos de mi Usuario y ordenador listos para añadir y hacer un commit con ello. Descarté los cambios porque la ruta era errónea en Visual Studio Code... y mi sorpresa es que me han desaparecido todos los docs, excel, pdfs, incluso la propia aplicación Visual Code Studio; y al intentar ejecutarla me indica que no estoy autorizado para abrir la aplicación y que contacte con el administrador para solicitar asistencia.

[image: En la terminal introduzco git status y me muestra que no tengo commits en la rama master y me indica los archivos que están pendientes de añadir.]

¿Qué debo hacer para restaurar todos estos cambios?
El disco duro externo para hacer copia o restaurar ahora ni lo detecta :(

Gracias
Un saludo